# Checking to see if the result of filter is an empty list

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

we've been ask to write a function to see if the result of an applied filter function is an empty list. I tried following approach but it gives me mentioned error.

```
isListEmpty ::((a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]) -> Bool
isListEmpty f       | length f == 0 = True
                    | otherwise = False
```

Error:

```
...- Type error in application
*** Expression     : length f
*** Term           : f
*** Type           : (b -> Bool) -> [b] -> [b]
*** Does not match : [a]
```

the idea is practicing higher order functions. 
any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: You didn't apply your filter function.  That's the error.

Comment: I wanted to use this function like `isListEmpty  (filter (\(x,y,_,_,_)-> x == user && y == pass ) y)`. in other words, filter function is an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you have wrong type annotations. Consider the following solution:

```
isListEmpty :: (a -> Bool)        -- filtering function
            -> [a]                -- given list
            -> Bool               -- the result
isListEmpty f = null . filter f
```

Some examples:

```
> isListEmpty odd [2, 4]
True
> isListEmpty odd [1, 2, 4]
False
>
```

Using `length` is not the best idea, since you have to loop through the entire list to do the check, and the list can even be infinite. `null` can handle this sutiation:

```
> isListEmpty even [1..]
False
>
```

**Edit 1**:

> our question asked us to use the built-in filter function as an argument

Don't quite understand what it means, but you may want to do this:

```
isListEmpty :: ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> Bool
isListEmpty = (null .)
```

Example usage:

```
> isListEmpty (filter even) [1..]
False
```

Please provide me with the example of intended function call, if I am wrong.

Comment: this function actually works but our question asked us to use the built-in filter function as an argument. here we did the filtering ourselves.

Comment: thanks! this is an example  `isListEmpty (filter (\(x,y,_,_,_)-> x == user && y == pass ) userList)`

Comment: @Elham, your example shows that the type of your function has to be the following: `isListEmpty :: [a] -> Bool`. That is in fact the `null` function. So you can just  define `isListEmpty` as follows: `isListEmpty = null` :)

Comment: you're right. I wrote the exact same thing in class but the lecturer asked me to write a HOF. >.< I suppose he could have meant to split the filtering function from it just like what you did. thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

```
isListEmpty ::((a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]) -> Bool
isListEmpty f       | length f == 0 = True
                    | otherwise = False
```

The first parameter of  your function `isListEmpty` is a function which you have given the name `f` and its type is `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a].` and you feed `f` to `length` this fails to work because the function `length` takes types with the signature of `[a]` and produces a type `Int`.

You can see this by going to ghci and typing `:t length` which produces `[a] -> Int`.

If you first apply f to a list which has a type `[a]` then you can use `length` and `==0` to check to see if it is empty.  The function `null` however is the idiomatic method for testing if a list is empty or not so I recommend use it instead.

Edit add example of how to go about writing a similar function.

Lets say I wanted to find the length of list after preforming another function like drop, or init etc. First just write the function in full with all arguments:

```
manipulateList :: ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> Int
manipulateList fn lst = length (fn lst)
```

Instead of `length (fn lst)` we can rewrite this with function coposition `(length.fn) lst`

```
manipulateList :: ([a] -> [a]) -> [a] -> Int
manipulateList fn lst = (length.fn) lst
```

Now you can cancel the `lst` on both sides much like you would with an algebra equation.

```
manipulateList :: ([a] -> [a]) -> Int
manipulateList fn = (length.fn)
```

Now we have a higher order function that takes a function `fn` and and find the length of list after `fn` is applied to it.

Comment: I know but this `length (filter (>2) [2,1,9])` works in Hugs.

Comment: After this comment I have a better idea of what you are trying to do. With `length (filter (>2) [2,1,9])` the filter function is first applied to the list, producing another list which you then find the length of.  With `length f` you are applying length to a function. I think I understand what you are trying to write now I will add an example to my answer.

Comment: That'd be great! Thank YOU!

Comment: @Elham does that example help clear up how you would go about writing the higher order function?

Comment: this is the first I learn about function composition. it's cool. I tried `length.f` but this composition is type of `([a] -> [a]) -> Int`

Comment: @Elham right now you can compose it with a testing function that takes `Int` and produces `Bool` so `Int -> Bool`. If you want to test to see if the length is zero.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23432/discussion-between-davorak-and-elham)

Answer (score 1):

First:
The error occurs because you treat this function like you only have one input, the list. Your type signature on the other hand requests a function from `a` to `Bool` and two `lists of type a.`

Second:
You said, you have to write a function, which tests, if a list, on which a filter function is applied, is empty. But you only test, if the list is empty, no application of your filter function (you didn't (like I described above) even do something with the function.

Third:
One little hint: Start with

```
isListEmpty f xs | length xs == 0 = True
                 | otherwise      = ...  ||  isListEmpty f ...
```

you have to fill something in for the `...` . 
`||` stands for Boolean "OR", if you don't know that.

Comment: oh I saw your comment at Davorak's post know. I thought, you are not allowed to use the `filter` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do :

```
null $ (filter (>2) [2,1,0]) ==> True
null $ (filter (>2) [2,1,9]) ==> False
```

with :

```
null :: [a] -> Bool
null [] = True
null _  = False
```

Or using HOF  (As said, this solution is wrong, I don't use HOF)

```
hof_null filter 
    | (null $ filter) = True
    | otherwise       = False


not_null (filter (>2) [1,1,3]) ==> False
not_null (filter (>2) [1,1,1]) ==> True
```

....

Last try, (thanks to Davorak)

```
hof_null fn = null.fn
```

Comment: null is a built-in function. the idea was using filter function as an argument for another higher-ordered-function.

Comment: There's no `HOF`s in your `hof_null` example. `hof_null` in fact is just a `null` alias.

Comment: Yes, that was my feeling too,thank to confirm, I will try something else